# How to create a random chance of word/sentence output in c++

Tags: c++, random, cpu-word, code-snippets

I was just wondering how I could do this. Here is he snippet of code I want this in:

```
/**< CASPOR's question script */
if (input == "N")
{
    cout << "Ok, " << name << " would you like to ask me a simple question?\n";
    cin >> input;
    {
        if (input == "Y")
        {
            while ("Y")
            {
                cout << "Ask away!\n";
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, input);
                {
                    if (input == "Who are you?")
                    {
                        cout << "I am CASPOR, or a C++ Automated Speech Program Of Recognition.\n";
                    }

                    if (input == "What is your purpose?")
                    {
                        cout << "My purpose is to entertain and amaze. Almost like a boredom breaker.\n";
                    }

                    if (input == "What can you do?")
                    {
                        cout << "I can do anything the developers program me to do!";
                    }
                    cout << "Would you like to ask another question?\n";
                    cin >> input;
                    {
                        if (input == "Y")
                            continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And around where `"CASPOR"` answers your questions, how can I include a chance that he is going to say something different each time?

Comment: What is going on with that spacing? It is very hard to read your code with that arbitrary indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your answers in a container (typically a `std::vector<std::string>>`) and use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to randomize it.

Then just select the first answer in the vector.

**Example:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    // Initialize the seed
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    // Store the answers
    std::vector<std::string> answers = { "Answer1" , "Answer2", "Answer3", "Answer4" };

    for(std::size_t n = 0 ; n <10 ; ++n)
    {
        // Randomize the vector
        std::shuffle(std::begin(answers), std::end(answers), std::default_random_engine(seed));
        std::cout << answers[0] << '\n';
    }
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e82aae4df5dbac19)

**Notes:**

- Your `if`'s should be `if ... else if ... else if ...`
- Your `while ("Y")` is pointless, just do `while(true)`

Answer (score 0):

you would have something like:

```
std::string possibleAnswers[] = {"Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "etc."};
```

Then maybe do something like:

```
std::cout << possibleAnswers[rand() % numPossibleAnswers] << "\n";
```

That is something basic, but if you want something more complicated you could setup a system that loads answers from a .csv where each line has possible answers to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Here a small example using `<random>` on vectors of predefined strings:

```
default_random_engine my_random;            // random generator  but not yet seeded -> so always the same numbers
my_random.seed(time(NULL));                 // intiialisze with at least a little bit of randomness

vector<string> sentences = { "Hello", "Hi !", "Happy to see you !", "etc..." };
uniform_int_distribution<int> sentences_dist(0, sentences.size()-1);    // uniform distribution between 0 and size of vector (equal proba to have any of it)

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    cout << sentences[sentences_dist(my_random)] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a question data-base and code a function that upon its evocation it will return a random question, like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <string>

std::array<std::string, 3> questions {"Who are you?", "What is your purpose?", "What can you do?"};

std::string random_question() {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, questions.size() - 1);

  return questions[dis(gen)];
}

int main() {
  for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) std::cout << random_question() << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2dae2151d9c71c3)